# Windows XP upgrade

Tags: windows

I am trying to upgrade an old Windows XP machine to Ubuntu. My question is can I install Ubuntu and keep my Windows XP files and how do I upgrade and keep those files?

Comment: you might want to read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Comment: Do you want to keep your Windows XP OS as well, or are you only interested in keeping you personal data files?

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that if you are planning to completely replace Windows XP with Ubuntu, you should **backup all your personal files from Windows XP**, either to a new partition, or an external hard drive, etc. because the new Ubuntu installation will overwrite Windows XP and unless you save your personal files somewhere, it will overwrite them too.